# How do I make push notifications work in production for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I didn't realize this until after I submitted my app to the App Store (and its now available) that there was a difference between a distribution and production token. During development, push notification worked for me, but after downloading it from the App Store, it didn't work.

I have push notifications enabled for development and distribution. I have created the appropriate development and distribution provisioning profile with push notifications enabled.

Some questions that I have is:

Is there anything I can do in my .php file, now that the app is in the app store, to allow push notification without submitting another update, i.e. changing the APNS server location from development to production?

Do I have to change how I fetch token within AppDelegate.m? Right now I have this within `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`:

```
NSString *token = [ [deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"] ];

// Remove spaces from the token
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

How can I test the production mode in Xcode? I have already created an Ad-Hoc certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make two changes to your `php` script, and the rest will work:

1. Change the destination to `gateway.push.apple.com:2195` instead of gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`.
2. Sign your push notification with a production certificate, instead of a development certificate.

The rest should work fine. Production tokens will have production push notifications sent accordingly.

Comment: 1. I did that already in the php file. 2. Not sure what you mean, I already have a APNs Production iOS certificate, if that's what you mean. However, it still does not seem to work. Don't I need to change how I fetch the token? The code I have fetches development tokens. Is there a difference?

Comment: Your tokens are fine. Regarding the certificate, when sending development pushes, do you remember generating a `.pem` file? You have to do that again, except using a distribution certificate instead of a development certificate.

Comment: Yes I generated a `.pem` file for development using this guide: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 , and I did the exact same thing for a distribution certificate. However, how can I get the production token to test it since Xcode won't allow the app to run on my device using a Distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: To test with a distribution certificate, create an AdHoc provisioning profile with your device then export it as an IPA file. From there, drag it into your device in organizer. You'll now have the app on your device in sending production certificates.

Answer (score 1):

- First export the ipa file with adhoc certificate and install it on    your iphone.
- By this way you can test your production cert But you    can't test(run) directly through xcode.
- Check your php side message is sent successfully or not.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I didn't upload the ck.pem file (combination of certificate and key) onto the server.

Now it's fixed.